# How to get same height rows with inline-grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I know how to get same height with `display:grid` css property.

But how I can get same height for all row elements with `display:inline-grid`.

Currently when I use it, some elements have less height if they've less content. I want to set height equally for all.

Edit:

I want to insert a DIV between 3 rows of grid. I made it possible with `inline-grid` but there is issue of height I described above. Is it possible to get this layout with `grid` property only?

[image]

Comment: Your questions is unclear. Code demonstrating your issue is also missing. `display:inline-grid;grid-auto-rows:1fr;` works as well as for  `display:grid;`. But you are probably after something else?

Answer (score -1):

Something like that:

```css
 body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  }
  .grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); /*  3 column grid */
    gap: 10px;
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto); 
  }
  .grid-item {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    padding: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; 
    justify-content: center; 
  }
```

```html
<h2>Equal Height Grid Items</h2>

<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">some short text</div>
  <div class="grid-item">long text long textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textvlong text</div>
  <div class="grid-item">medium text text text text</div>
  <div class="grid-item">text text</div>
  <div class="grid-item">line break<br>line break<br>line break</div>
  <div class="grid-item">text text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is okay, but actually I've requirement of inserting a `div` after 3 rows and before next 3 rows.

That is:

I want grid with 3 elements per row and 3 rows with that.
After this I want to insert a DIV in the middle.
Then again I have 3 rows with 3 elements per row.

Currently I'm adding it with `inline-grid`.

Can I do same with `grid` only property?

Comment: Updated the question with more information.